# Is it unholy to represent the moon sideways like the horns of a cow?

Tags: moon

In all the history of Islam, where is the moon represented with upwards points?

When we see the clock above the tomb of Mohammad, we think:  *It looks like the horns of a bull!* We do not understand why there are horns on top of the clock.

Muslims do not like the Saud tower clock, because Mohammad and Moses both said: Do not worship the cow. The moon is holy in Islam, and all islamic flags have an upright moon, never looking like horns.

Did the Saudi architects make a mistake to put the moon sideways? Is it an unholy sign, to put horns on top of a minaret? Was there condemnation from Imams?

Comment: What is the definition of Holy in Islam, I don't know about any!

Comment: Please explain the relationship between worshiping a cow and the Saudi Tower Clock. Do you mean the tower is a cow and Muslims worship the tower? Also, where in Islamic text does it say that the moon is holy?

Answer (score 1):

The moon is not holy in Islam as there is no evidence to show that and nor was it a symbol that was used by the Prophet (SAW). So, it doesn't matter how the people draw the moon. They can draw it upright or they can draw it sideways or they can draw it diagonal. It doesn't make a difference.